# find query of chat collection executes pre middleware of message collection which ends ups going into an infinite loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

**Description:**
I was using .populate methods with every find query, which worked OK until I decided to utilize pre-middleware to populate the fields so that I didn't have to write .populate with every find query in my APIs. Now the question is if I should reverse my changes back to use populate with every find query or if there is another way to prevent the message schema pre-middleware from continuing into an infinite loop.

**Get Chats API:**

```
const Chat = require("../../models/chat");
const getChats = async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log('time to get chats');
    const chats = await Chat.find({ users: { $in: [req.user._id] } }).sort({ createdAt: 
-1 });
    console.log('chats', chats);
    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        chats
    })
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message
    })
}

 }
 module.exports = getChats;
```

**Results in infinete loop**

[image]

**Chat Model :**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose
 const chatModel = Schema(
{
    chatName: { type: String, trim: true },
    isGroupChat: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    groupChatImage: String,
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
    latestMessage: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "message" },
    groupAdmin: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
},
{
    timestamps: true
});



chatModel.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
this.populate({
    path: 'users',
    select: "_id name email profileImage"
}).populate({
    path: 'latestMessage',
    populate: {
        path: 'senderId recieverId',
        select: '-password -__v'
    }
}).populate({
    path: 'groupAdmin',
    select: "_id name email profileImage"
})

next();
})

const Chat = mongoose.model("chat", chatModel);
module.exports = Chat;
```

**Message Model :**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const messageSchema = Schema(
{
    senderId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
    message: { type: String, trim: true },
    chatId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "chat" },
    recieverId: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }],
    stars: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" }]
},
{ timestamps: true }
);

let count=1;
messageSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
console.log('messageSchema pre find middleware', count++, this.message);
this.populate({
    path: 'senderId',
    select: '-password -__v'
})
    .populate({
        path: 'recieverId',
        select: '-password -__v'
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'chatId',
        populate: {
            path: 'users',
            select: '-password -__v'
        }
    });
next();
 });

  const Message = mongoose.model("message", messageSchema);
  module.exports = Message;
```